# 2 logarithmic questions: Two inequalities and one inverse related

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms, exponential-function, inverse

I have attached the image below depicting the problems and my solutions or what I had attempted so far.

For Q3(a):3cosx = 2x for -π *<* x *<* π (less than or equal to sign)
[I attempted formatting as Tex command - hope this works]
$$
3\cos{x} = 2x, \text{for} -\pi \leq x \leq \pi
$$

\begin{align*}
\text{Graphically the point of intersection is :} 0.915 
\end{align*}

(However when I check by inputting the value of 0.915 in the original functions, both answers are different - for example: e.g. $3\cos{0.915} = 2.999$ vs. $2(0.915) = 1.83$)
\begin{align*}
\ 3cos(0.915) \ = 2.999 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\ vs. 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\ 2(0.915) \ = \ 1.83 
\end{align*}

Q8: I think I did the inverse part correctly and composed $f^{-1}(x)$ into $f(x)$ correctly. I am not sure how to proceed to verify that the inverse is equivalent to $x$.

Once again, thank you very much for help. Best community right here!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, the solution is effectively $x\approx 0.915$ but the result is in **radians**.

Checking $$3 \cos(0.915)-2\times 0.915=-0.000628274$$ while, if, by mistake, your calculator is set for **degrees**, $3 \cos (0.915 {}^{\circ})=2.99962$.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question $f(x)=3\log(x+1)$

The inverse of $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)=e^{\frac x3}-1$

Now $f(f^{-1}(x))=3\log(e^{\frac x3}-1+1)=x$